# Redirect postgres connectby into a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, create-table, connect-by

I am using postgres 9.6 with the tablefunc expansion to generate a hierarchial table using the connectby function.  My syntax is

```
SELECT * 
FROM connectby('depTree2', 'id', 'parentid', 'sequence', '{4472}',0)
AS t(keyid text, parent_keyid text, level int, pos int)
```

Once I collect get the data there is more post processing that I would like to do with it so I need to direct the output of the connectby command into a table.  I tried adding INTO on either side of the AS phrase but no luck.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: `create table tree as select ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you wat `insert ... select`?

```
INSERT INTO target_table(keyid text, parent_keyid text, level int, pos int)
SELECT * 
FROM connectby('depTree2', 'id', 'parentid', 'sequence', '{4472}',0)
AS t(keyid text, parent_keyid text, level int, pos int)
```

This works if you have an already-existing table. On the other hand if ou want to create a new table, then:

```
CREATE TABLE target_table AS
SELECT * FROM connectby('depTree2', 'id', 'parentid', 'sequence', '{4472}',0)
AS t(keyid text, parent_keyid text, level int, pos int)
```